# Order columns Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a Dataframe with the following columns

> Index(['Carteira', 'Cobrança', 'XP Investimentos', 'Itau', 'Santander',
> 'Unicred', 'XP Invetsimentos', 'Interactive Brokers', 'BDMG', 'XP US',
> 'Itaú', 'Votorantim', 'Banco do Brasil', 'Itau Miami', 'Bradesco',
> 'Sicoob', 'XP', 'Safra', 'Fundo Exclusivo', 'BNP Paribas',
> 'XP investimentos', 'BB', 'Caixa', 'Charles Schwab', 'Itaú Unibanco',
> '%Comissão Assessor', 'Codigo XP', 'Assessor', 'Filial'],
> dtype='object')

I want to sort these columns, but in my code I don't know the names of all the columns.
So I don't want to sort the columns as code below:

```
newdf = df[['Carteira', 'Cobrança', 'XP Investimentos', 'Itau', 'Santander',
   'Unicred', 'XP Invetsimentos', 'Interactive Brokers', 'BDMG', 'XP US',
   'Itaú', 'Votorantim', 'Banco do Brasil', 'Itau Miami', 'Bradesco',
   'Sicoob', 'XP', 'Safra', 'Fundo Exclusivo', 'BNP Paribas',
   'XP investimentos', 'BB', 'Caixa', 'Charles Schwab', 'Itaú Unibanco',
   '%Comissão Assessor', 'Codigo XP', 'Assessor', 'Filial']]
```

I need to move the last 4 columns to position 2, 3, 4 and 5.
example: ['Carteira', 'Cobrança', '%Comissão Assessor', 'Codigo XP', 'Assessor', 'Filial', ...]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `iloc` with `np.r_`

```
>>> df.iloc[:, np.r_[0, 1, -4, -3, -2, -1, 2:len(df.columns)]]
```